# Captive Portal for devices behind NAT: Is it possible?

Tags: wifi, captive-portal

A related question:

> [Do all captive portal solutions work the same way? (cookie, vs MAC address, vs other?)](https://serverfault.com/questions/629016/do-all-captive-portal-solutions-work-the-same-way-cookie-vs-mac-address-vs-o)

I have been reading about **Captive Portal** at [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Captive_portal).

This part generates a question:

> A captive portal that uses MAC addresses to track connected devices
>   can sometimes be circumvented by connecting via hard-wire a router
>   that allows setting of the router MAC address. Many router firmwares
>   call this MAC cloning.

As long as Wikipedia talks about `captive portal that uses **MAC addresses**`, is there any **other method** for tracking/managing them?

**Reason** for asking this: I am planning to set up a captive portal for the WiFi service offered to the clients in a **hotel**. As for today, the repeaters ([Routerboard](https://wiki.openwrt.org/toh/mikrotik/rb951ui)) are configured to work in **router** mode, as long as I prefer it over access point mode. So, the **MAC Address** of any connected client will not be *seen* by the Gateway managing the captive portal.

Can I implement some sort of **captive portal** for access control in this case?

**Note**:

- Please, this question is not "Is it better router mode over access point mode for WiFi repeaters?". I actually **want** to keep my repeaters in **router** mode. I **don't** want to change them. Save answers like "it is preferred to use access point mode because..." for another thread, not this one.

Comment: You must have the MAC address to distinguish devices.

Answer (score 3):

You might be able to get a small portion of your clients to accept a captive portal.  However, these may break security of connections, so clients that need secure connections are likely to refused your service and switch to a different hotel.  It is unlikely you will be able to easily lure those clients back.

Very few protocols allow injection of something into the data stream, that would allow tracking a device by anything but MAC address or the associated IP address.

- HTTP allows setting cookies, but those are specific to domains.
- IPv6 introduced temporary addresses which breaks IP address tracking.

In the end you are stuck with tracking MAC addresses.